# collectionview, SelfSizing cells pinterest layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have implemented a collectionview as described here https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swift-programming/flexible-cell-sizes-collection-view-layout-swift
but the problem is when i tried to initialize the height from the layout Delegate I get  "Value of type 'PopularAndRecentUpload' has no member 'size'". I made the class with all the properties that would go into the cell.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 import UIKit
    //Mark Public API

    class PopularAndRecentUpload{
        var CellImage:UIImage
        var Username = ""
        var UserPosition = ""
        var numberOfLikes = ""
        var LoveImage: UIImage
        var color:UIColor


        init(CellImage:UIImage,Username:String,UserPosition:String,numberOfLikes:String,LoveImage:UIImage,color:UIColor) {
            self.CellImage = CellImage
            self.Username = Username
            self.UserPosition = UserPosition
            self.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes
            self.LoveImage = LoveImage
            self.color = color
        }





        //Mark private Dummy Data
        static func fetchPhotos()->[PopularAndRecentUpload]{

            return[
                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "9")!, Username: "@모로 압둘 카림", UserPosition: "1 등", numberOfLikes: "123k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),

                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "8")!, Username: "박형준", UserPosition: "2등", numberOfLikes:"120k", LoveImage:UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),

                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "7")!, Username: "박희찬", UserPosition: "3등", numberOfLikes: "110k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),
                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "6")!, Username: "Malori", UserPosition: "4등", numberOfLikes: "110k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),
                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "5")!, Username: "종호", UserPosition: "5등", numberOfLikes: "110k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),

                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "4")!, Username: "서원석", UserPosition: "6등", numberOfLikes: "10", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),
                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "3")!, Username: "민지혜", UserPosition: "7등", numberOfLikes: "110k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),
                PopularAndRecentUpload(CellImage: UIImage(named: "2")!, Username: "박희찬", UserPosition: "3등", numberOfLikes: "110k", LoveImage: UIImage(named: "icon-like-filled")!, color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)),

         ]
        }
    }




    import UIKit
    class PopularAndRecentPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var CellImageView: UIImageView!


 @IBOutlet weak var UsernameTitleLable:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserPositionLable:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfLikesLable:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoveImageView:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WhitebackGroundPadding:UIView!



    var popularAndRecentPhotos: PopularAndRecentUpload? {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }

    private func updateUI()
    {
        if let popularAndRecentPhotos = popularAndRecentPhotos{
            CellImageView.image = popularAndRecentPhotos.CellImage
            UsernameTitleLable.text = popularAndRecentPhotos.Username
            UserPositionLable.text = popularAndRecentPhotos.UserPosition
            numberOfLikesLable.text = popularAndRecentPhotos.numberOfLikes
            LoveImageView.image = popularAndRecentPhotos.LoveImage
            WhitebackGroundPadding.backgroundColor = popularAndRecentPhotos.color

        } else {

            CellImageView.image = nil
            UsernameTitleLable.text = nil
            UserPositionLable.text = nil
            numberOfLikesLable.text = nil
            LoveImageView.image = nil
            WhitebackGroundPadding.backgroundColor = nil
        }
    }


}






//ViewController.


import UIKit
class PopularAndRecentPhotosViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!



    // mark properties

    var popularPhotos = [PopularAndRecentUpload.fetchPhotos()]



    //var uploadedphotos = [ [UIImage(named: "1"),UIImage(named: "2"),UIImage(named: "3"),UIImage(named: "4"),UIImage(named: "5"),UIImage(named: "6"),UIImage(named: "7"),UIImage(named: "8")],[UIImage(named: "f4"),UIImage(named: "f7") ]]

    var p :Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? LiquidCollectionViewLayout{
            layout.delegate = self
        }

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        p = 0

    }

    // SegmentedControl
    @IBAction func SwitchToPopularOrRecentPhotos(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
                p = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
                collectionView.reloadData()  
    }

}

extension PopularAndRecentPhotosViewController:LiquidLayoutDelegate{
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForCellAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let cell = popularPhotos[p][indexPath.item]
        let height = cell.size.height

        return height
    }
}

extension PopularAndRecentPhotosViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return popularPhotos[p].count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularAndRecentPhotoCell

        cell.popularAndRecentPhotos = popularPhotos[p][indexPath.item]
        return cell

    }
}
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIcLN.png)

Comment: can you please show the code as where are you setting the height.

Comment: What is `PopularAndRecentUpload`?  `PopularAndRecentUpload` has to be a `kind` of UIView, to have a size property.

Comment: Yes please I have update my question. And  the PopularAndRecentUpload is the class with properties.   Do I have to inherit it with UIview?